# ConnMan missing from e17

Tags: 12.04, enlightenment

I installed e17 using the Ubuntu software center in my Ubuntu 12.04. When I logged into e17 and tried to connect into wireless, it was showing that ConnMan was missing. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo apt-get install connman`? You can also look for it in the software center.

Comment: I tried installing connman via the software centre, but it showed that the default internet connection managers have to be uninstalled first to install connman, so I didn't try further. Anyway, thanks a lot for your advice.